# Como desinstalar tomcat 8.5 en CENTOS 7

Tags: linux, servidor, tomcat, centos, yum

Estoy configurando un servidor en Centos 7 pero estoy teniendo algunos problemas con el tomcat. Al querer ingresar al Manager o al Host-manager, por eso es que quiero saber como puedo eliminar completamente el tomcat para volverlo a instalar.

Comment: ¿Cómo se instalo amigo?

Comment: Descargué el tar de la página y lo descomprimí, configuré los permisos para los directorios y luego configuré el archivo del tomcat.service

Comment: Toda la instalación debe ser precisamente el archivo descomprimido. Los temporales y los logs de arranque deben generarse dentro del directorio descomprimido cada vez que se arranque el servidor (salvo aplicaciones desplegadas que deliberadamente afecten otros directorios del sistema operativo).